# My account won't somehow be deleted

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

[image]

I did the whole unregistering procedure, and nothing happens. This account had to be deleted since around 35 minutes soon. What is going on?

Comment: Well, seeing as the account is now deleted, it looks like it was just the job trying to catch up.

Comment: @phantom42 Who was this guy? Do we know him?

Comment: @SachinShekhar I remember seeing the name a few times, but he wasn't one of the heavy users as far as participation goes.

Answer (score 6):

It seems like the timing isn't precise with such things. If anyone in the future has this problem, take a deep breath, wait a couple hours, and then if there's an issue, feel free to bring it up.

Comment: Also, if I've you've given it an extra couple hours and are still waiting, it's also fine to reach out to the Community Team through the [contact form](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/contact) at that point. But really, chances are the robots are just feeling a little sleepy.