# Why hasn't my account been deleted?

Tags: support

[image]

It's been 2 days (going on 3), and it still hasn't been deleted! [I'm sure the timing system can't be *that* far off!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5287/my-account-wont-somehow-be-deleted)

Comment: As far as I know the time given is just an estimation given normal processing times. I think an employee handles the request so just depends on how busy they are.

Comment: Because half the CM team got fired or quit and deleting your account is very low on their list of priorities

Comment: [It has](https://secure.i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/01112/mission_accomplish_1112950c.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Account deletion when an account has cast a lot of votes, presumably you have, only takes place “once a week” and has to be done by an employee. Given the team has recently lost a few members and different priorities going on account deletion may take longer than usual. See the [relevant meta FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7979/345161):

> If your account has cast a lot of votes, it will not be deleted approximately after the 24-hour timer expires, as above. Deletion will be held up while a Stack Exchange employee checks your account to determine if your votes should be preserved (in most cases, they are, but in some cases, such as your account having a history of voting fraud, they aren't). During this hold-up, you may see a deletion notice that says that your account is scheduled to be deleted for some date in the past; this is confusing, but not a sign of a bug.
>
> The queue of accounts awaiting deletion is generally processed every Friday, or the previous or next business day if Friday is a holiday. This means that if your account falls into this queue, it could take up to five business days for your deletion request to be processed.
>
> If your account has not been deleted and it's been more than five business days (weekdays, excluding U.S. holidays) since the timer has expired, it's possible that the team simply has not cleared out the queue of accounts awaiting deletion; send a contact request using the contact form to remind them.

Personally I would wait until next week before contacting the team if your account has not been deleted by then. Remember on top of everything there is a lot going on in the world right now.